# How to record a conference call within a Twilio runtime function?

Tags: twilio, twilio-functions

This Twilio runtime function creates a conference, but I am unable to figure out how to activate recording.

```
exports.handler = function(context, event, callback) {
    let twiml = new Twilio.twiml.VoiceResponse();
    twiml.say("You have joined my conference bridge");
    let conferenceName = "My Conference Bridge";
    twiml.dial().conference(conferenceName);
    callback(null, twiml);
};
```

[screenshot of the runtime function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xt8Fv.png)

Comment: try `twiml.record();` before callback, also check the attributes https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/twiml/record#attributes

Comment: Thanks for your resonse @AlexBaban. I have tried `twiml.record();`, the function did not return any error, but call wasn't recorded. No warning or error message in the diagnostic log. Also tried  additing an attribute `twiml.record(timeout="30");`, the function did not return any error, the call wasn't recorded, and now I see Warning - 12200 in the diagnostic log, it says **parserMessage** *" Element 'Record' must have no character or element information item [children]"*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this.

```
    exports.handler = function(context, event, callback) {
    let twiml = new Twilio.twiml.VoiceResponse();
    twiml.say("You will now be entered into your confernece");
    twiml.dial().conference({record: 'record-from-start'}, 'myconference');
    callback(null, twiml);
};
```

Comment: Thank you so much, this solved my problem. Have a great day :-)